# Remote video controls controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is the situation. A teacher wants to display in his students's computers a video. But only display it. Students can not play, pause, stop... anything. On the students's screen only appears the video being controlled remotely by the teacher. So, teacher wants students to listen the from minute 1:00 until 1:20. He controls the video and students watch what the teacher wants them to watch. This has to be done through Internet. The tools I have available are a hosting and domain, PHP, MySQL. I was thinking to use AJAX but since not all students will have the same Internet quality connection I thought some will have significant delays. Controls (pause, play, forward to minute 2:30, etc...) must be sent as fast as possible from the teacher and the students must receive those controls in their computer as fast as possible too, so that there is no delay. There will be delay, obviously, but it must be the minimum possible. I searched a similar tool to do this but Google did not help much. Do you know of any? And if not, how would you implement it (being aware the available tools I have). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the mysql database, since the question is clearly unrelated to databases.

Comment: This sounds like the job for a screensharing or video streaming service. Maybe set up the teacher on youtube live? and employ https://obsproject.com/

Comment: We tried screensharing but delays occur. The idea is that students connect to, say: example.com/video and first all the video is downloaded to her computer. Then, the teacher only sends. say, a string like: goto:1:20, so student just receives this short string and via javascript I control the video to go to minute 1:20

Comment: yes you could code something like that. But I really think OBS is probably the best way to go, you should look into it. It can stream video files on your local machine to a variety of different live platforms with control for pause, seek, etc. Or screenshare if that's easier for the teacher. Your webapp strategy would likely require something like socket.io and a dedicated server to manage the pushes to the clients.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for, code-wise: http://reactphp.org since you mentioned PHP (apparently no relation to ReactJs)

Comment: Thanks! Apparently socket.io is the tool I need! I'll give it a try! Thanks again!